# Simple Swipe in Swift - xCode 6

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6, swipe-gesture

I'm trying to make a simple swipe up gesture, I dragged the Swipe Gesture Recogniser over a UIImage, I then Ctrl button drag the Swipe Gesture to my swift file and create the following Action: -

```
@IBAction func swipeDice(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    //Test display
    testLabel.text = "Zing"
}
```

The app builds and runs successfully however when I test the swipe gesture it doesn't seem to do anything.

Is that all the code I need for the gesture to run?
How do I make it recognise a 2 finger swipe gesture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable User Interaction for the `UIImage` that you added the `UIGestureRecognier` to:

Open the *Attributes Inspector* for the `UIImage` and tick **User Interaction Enabled**:

[image: Enabling User Interaction on a UIImage]

Answer (score 1):

If you created the Swipe Gesture Recognizer in IB you can setup the gesture through the right window.

[image]

If you have a conflict between several gestures you can handle this through the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol.

Comment: So the code should look like this?

    @IBAction func swipeDice(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    
        func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
            
            return true
        }
        //Test display
        testLable.text = "Zing"
    }

Comment: You always should check the `state` of an `UIGestureRecognizer` as some could trigger the function with failed states. But is as simple as it looks

Comment: If the two gestures are in different directions or different number of touches required you may not need the `shouldRecognizeSimultaneous`

Comment: I'm voting your answer up because it answers the second part of the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following function to your code:

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: I did, but nothing happened? Should this replace my IBAction?

Comment: No, it tells the user interface that several gesture recognizer can work in parallel